# Error using arcpy.da.SearchCursor and MakeFeatureLayer

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy

im trying to write a script that allows me to iterate through my map layers, and for each layer, iterate over each feature and add a field that gives the location of the feature using my index layer as reference. In other words, I want to know where every single feature is in relation to the index layer. The index layer is comprised of many polygons called "zones". So every feature should have a field that tells me which zone it is in. This is what I have so far :

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\Zonetrial.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Main Map")[0]
lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"",df)
fieldname = "Zone"
type = "TEXT"
inlayer = "layeritem2"
inlayer1 = "Zoneitem"

#for layeritem in lyrList:
    #if layeritem.name == "Zone of Interest":
        #Zones = set([r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layeritem, "ZoneName")])
       #print Zones
for layeritem in lyrList:
    if layeritem.name == "Zone of Interest":
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layeritem, "ZoneName") as cursor:  
            for Zone in cursor:
                print Zone
                arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Zone,inlayer1)
                print Zone
                for layeritem in lyrList:
                    if layeritem.name == "AllZones_Topology":
                        print "Nothing will happen to " + layeritem.name
                    elif layeritem.name == "UWI Campus Boundary":
                        print "Nothing will happen to " + layeritem.name
                    elif layeritem.name == "Zone of Interest":
                       print "Nothing will happen to " + layeritem.name
                    elif layeritem.name == "polytrial selection 5":
                        print "Nothing will happen to " + layeritem.name 
                    else:    
                        print layeritem
                        print Zone
                        arcpy.AddField_management (layeritem,fieldname,type)
                        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(layeritem,inlayer)
                        #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Zone,inlayer1)
                        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(inlayer,"intersect",inlayer1)
                        arcpy.CalculateField_management(inlayer,fieldname,Zone)


print "Script Finished!"
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
(u'1',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 326, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT\Scripts\Zonesort10.py", line 20, in <module>
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Zone,inlayer1)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 5774, in MakeFeatureLayer
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

I think I am using the wrong SearchCursor or I am using it wrong. Help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you're using a tuple (returned from your cursor) as your input for your `MakeFeatureLayer_management`. This function requires a feature class or layer as its input.

If you're wanting to know where your layers lie in relationship to a polygon, I suggest using a `spatial join` as opposed to a cursor. It is faster, and a good tool to have in your toolkit. If your input is not a point feature class already, I suggest a `FeatureToPoint` conversion to eliminate potential boundary issues.